# Static variable resetting in C after value 0x0c

Tags: c, static, reset

I am trying to read continuous data from remote device and I have static variable declared to receive and send ACK . `Payload of 0 and 1` holds the sequence number of the data I am getting from remote device .

The problem I have is with variable `fragment_num`. After it reaches `0x0c` it is resetting back to 0.

Its Free RTOS application . Are there any obvious reasons for a static variable to reset to 0 or is there any problem with my code ? Thanks

```
#define INTIAL_FRAGMENT 0x00
static uint8_t length;
static uint8_t fragment_num ;
uint8_t image[128];
download ()
{
  if(((payload[1] << 8) | (payload[0])) == INTIAL_FRAGMENT)
{
  memset(image , 0,128);
  memcpy(image , payload,(len));
  info_download();
  length = len;
  fragment_num +=1 ;
 
}

   if(((payload[1] << 8) | (payload[0])) == fragment_num)
{
  memcpy((image+length+1) , payload,(len));
  length += len;
  fragment_num ++;
  info_download();
}
```

Comment: That `download()` function is invalid. It must have a type, like `void`. It's also missing the end `}` - and please format the code consistently to make it easier to read it.

Comment: And the variable `len` is not defined. Copy and paste your complete code when you post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely buffer overflow.

```
static uint8_t fragment_num ;
uint8_t image[128];
```

The compiler may have laid out `fragment_num` right after `image` in memory. If `length` or `len` is incorrect then `memcpy()` could write past the end of `image` and overwrite the value of `fragment_num`.

```
memcpy((image+length+1) , payload,(len));
```

I believe you want `(image+length)` instead of `(image+length+1)` here. Adding one skips a byte.

You should probably also verify `len` before `memcpy()` to make sure it doesn't overflow, e.g.:

```
if (len > 128)
    return -1;
memcpy(image, payload, len);
```

```
if (length + len > 128)
    return -1;
memcpy(image + length, payload, len);
```

Comment: Thank you! That was correct . I fixed the length and len and increased the buffer and it worked !!